# Execute dynamic HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a textarea and a division so that whatever embed code you put in the textarea it gets executed on the division in real-time.

Your kind help is greatly appreciated!

JavaScript newbie

Here's an attempt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var X = " HTML or JavaScript "
window.onload=function()
{
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("input").value;
}
</script>

<textarea id="input" cols="35" rows="7"> X </textarea>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: 'and a division' is not clear - please rewrite your question or request

Comment: See the source code of this site: http://jsfiddle.net/.

Comment: @Blender - The source of jsfiddle is a bit daunting for a beginner dontcha think? ;)

Comment: So is making a clone of it ;)

Comment: @mozillanerd, Sorry if it wasn't clear! I'd like the code to be run in a <div> in real time (as soon as I type/paste the code in the textarea).

Comment: It's impractical to execute JavaScript "in real time".

Answer (score 1):

This will evaluate the contents of the textarea when you click anywhere outside of the textarea. *(Code updated to set result from source (`<textarea/>`) as HTML if source begins with a less-than ('<') or the result of evaluating source as Javascript.)*

```
<textarea id="js" onBlur="run(this)"></textarea>

<div id="result">Result goes here!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function run(elt){
    var target_div=document.getElementById('result'),
        result='';

    if(target_div) {
      if(elt.value.match(/^\s*</)) { // content of textarea begins with less-than
        result=elt.value;
      }
      else { // eval content of textarea as Javascript
        try {
          result=eval(elt.value);
        }
        catch (e) {
          alert('failed to eval source:'+e.description);
        }
      } // else match
      if(result) {
        target_div.innerHTML=result;
      }
    } // if target_div
    return false;
  } // end run
</script>
```

Of course it's usually considered a VERY BAD IDEA to allow a user to execute arbitrary code. ;-)

Comment: The provided code works in Chrome 11.0.696.65 and should work in other browsers as well.  You need to enter raw javascript without <script> tags, like: [ 1+1 ] which will change the content of the result div to '2'

Comment: @Hermes, sorry I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Would you please try this sample code: <div style="color:red">Text</div>

Comment: @Rob R - I think you should replace *innerText* with *innerHTML*. Until HTML5, *innerText* was MS proprietary and not that widely supported. Also, not too worried about *eval* in this scenario, it's no more dangerous than `javascript:...` in the address bar.

Comment: @Hermes, you need to do a little work and try to learn what the heck you are doing. This is a fairly simple thing to do, but you haven't done much investigating yourself. And what the heck does "Would you please try this sample code: <div style="color:red">Text</div>" mean? Try it yourself for Petes sake! Yes it is hard. Programming is hard. I just would encourage you to try to figure out as much as possible yourself. Then your questions will be better, and you will learn more, faster. Good luck on this project.

Comment: @Rob +1 Nice implementation. Does exactly what Hermes asks for.

Comment: Dear Byron, I did 'a lot of' search and read some articles before I ask the question here and even after that. I just came up to the code I updated in my question. All I need is using eval function to get the whole code (HTML / JavaScript) as a variable. I still don't know how to do it and am badly stuck! Please help me!

Comment: @Byron, Sure! It doesn't work with a JavaScript embed code, e.g. <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<h1>This is a heading</h1>");</script>, and it doesn't run HTML embeddings. As my question title says I'd like it to run HTML or JavaScript embed codes, e.g. a music player embed code.

Comment: Hermes, ok, code updated to insert HTML into result if source (textarea) starts with a less-than '<', or the result of evaluating the source as javascript.

Comment: Dear Rob, I really appreciate your time and continuous help! However, it still doesn't support JavaScript well. Here's a clock embed code I tried:`code` <div id="wpdc_embed_12830726823" style="display: none">Time &amp; Date Widget</div><head></head><script src="http://www.widgipedia.com/embed/martinkorner/Time--Date-Widget_776w-12830726823t-1283072682143i-8192p.js"></script>`code`

Comment: Hermes, Um..ok, other than the use of <head/> within the body of an HTML document which is not legal HTML, your example is incomplete. Perhaps if you start another question with a clear description of your problem including example code?

Comment: Sorry I don't know exactly how to insert a code in this forum comments. Here's where I got the code: [link](http://www.widgipedia.com/widgets/customize/martinkorner/Time--Date-Widget_776.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`Eval()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)

Here is some code to get you started.

```
 <textarea id='js'>window.alert('Hello Cruel World');</textarea> <input type=submit onclick="run()" value="run">
 <script>
 function run ()
 {
      eval(document.getElementById('js').value);
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: @Byron - `input type="button"` would probably be better. And where is the interaction with a div?

Comment: @Byron, Seems great, but I don't want a button. I'd like the code to be run in a <div> in real time (as soon as I type/paste the code in the textarea). Besides it doesn't seem to work with pure HTML embeddings.

Comment: @Hermes How do you plan to tell the difference between a script someone is half finished writing and trying to run that, and a script that is completely finished?

Comment: @Hermes: Let me quote Sir Byron. "Here is some code _to get you started._"

Comment: @djlumley, If the interaction between the textarea and division is  in real-time, once the code is finished, e.g. by putting an end tag, it gets executed on the div.

Comment: @Levi Morrison, I see and I appreciate Byron's hint, but as a beginner I really need more than a pointer.

Comment: @Hermes You can use onKeyDown to check for key presses, depending on the amount of functionality you might find it easier to use a library like jQuery to help you manage the events.
I'm not sure how you're going to reliably check for an "end tag" without it being overly complex, but Byron's code should be enough to get you started given all you're doing is really changing what calls the run function, and targeting any appending etc to a div element.

Comment: @djlumley, "depending on the amount of functionality you might find it easier to use a library like jQuery to help you manage the events." I don't know how to do it. Would you mind providing an example?

Comment: @Hermes - http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner
There's quite a few JavaScript and jQuery tutorials available on the internet. My approach would be to understand the language you want to code in, then try to do something more complicated like this in it :)