# Render vanilla JS <script> from API Response NOT working in the Angular 16

Tags: angular, angular-dom-sanitizer

Let's consider that I am getting a response (as below) from api

**Response**

```
{
  embedEmail: "\n<div style='text-align:left'>\n  <input \n    type=\"email\" \n    id=\"textboxID_4204617a-0b6b-4676-880c-be963ee6ce74\" \n    data-expression='9'\n  >\n  </input>\n  <small style=\"display: block; margin-top: 0.5rem; margin-bottom: 0.5rem; color: crimson\" \n  id=\"textBoxemailHelpId\">\n  </small>\n</div><br/>\n<script>\nconst textBoxHtmlInputElement_4204617a_0b6b_4676_880c_be963ee6ce74_email = this.document.getElementById('textboxID_4204617a-0b6b-4676-880c-be963ee6ce74');\nconsole.log('textBoxHtmlInputElement_4204617a_0b6b_4676_880c_be963ee6ce74_email:', textBoxHtmlInputElement_4204617a_0b6b_4676_880c_be963ee6ce74_email)\n</script>\n"
}
```

I am able to render the HTML content present in the `embedEmail` with the help of a pipe which uses`DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml()`.

But the challenge I am facing here is, the content inside the `<script></script>` tags is not rendered.

**How to overcome this behavior so that I could render the script?**

> **Some background information on what I am trying to achieve with the above stuff:**
>
> I am having an application where one end-user (using angular) saves the **Input fields & it's respective validations** as a string `(i.e., stringified some HTML with some inline CSS and JS)` in the DB.
>
> This saved content string needs to be retrieved back as normal HTML for another end-user (using .NET) with all the CSS and JS applied properly.
>
> Any other suggestions appreciated, but request you to address the above query too...

Comment: You will have the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77328994/how-to-execute-evaluate-dynamic-mix-of-html-and-javascript-code-and-the-result-t . I also faced the same issue and the solution is not very easy or intuitive but there at least there is a workaround.